# C++: Why does the compiler instantiate a template when it is not used

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, instantiation

Let's consider this code:

```
template <bool c>
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    // I want to enable f(int) only if c == true
    template<typename Temp = typename enable_if<c>::type>
    void f(int val) {
        cout << val << endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    A<false> a;
    A<true> b;
    b.f(543);
}
```

When I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

But I don't use the template method `f(int)` when the argument `<bool c>` is `false` then it shouldn't exist.

Comment: `enable_if` is for *deduced* template parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not "instantiate" your template, as you seem to incorrectly believe. The compiler is simply trying to parse and analyze your template declaration, which is a part of your class definition. If the class is instantiated, then all member *declarations* have to be valid. Your member template declaration is not valid. Hence the error.

If some template is "not used", it means that it does not get specialized and instantiated. But the *declaration* of that template still has to be valid. And the validity of those parts of that declaration that *do not depend on template parameters* is checked immediately. In other words, what you wrote in your code is no different from

```
template <typename T = jksgdcaufgdug> void foo() {}

int main() {}
```

or, closer to your situation

```
template <typename T = std::enable_if<false>::type> void foo() {}

int main() {}
```

Even though these programs do not "use" (do not instantiate) function template `foo`, it still does not mean that the declaration of `foo` can contain random garbage like `jksgdcaufgdug` or explicitly refer to non-existent entities like `std::enable_if<false>::type`. The above examples will not compile for that reason.

You can use "random garbage" in *dependent* contexts, like

```
template <typename T> void foo(typename T::kjhdfjskhf x) 
{ 
  typename T::jksgdcaufgdug i; 
}
```

and you can use `std::enable_if` in dependent contexts like

```
template <typename T, 
          typename U = typename enable_if<is_void<T>::value>::type>
void bar()
{ 
}
```

and it will not produce "early" errors, but in your case `enable_if<c>` does not depend on `Temp`, so it is not in dependent context. Which means that the correctness of `typename enable_if<c>::type` is checked immediately when you instantiate `A<false>`.